# Issues with line-clearing algorithm for Tetris game?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a text-based Tetris game and running into some issues with clearing lines. I have my DeleteRow() method which deletes the given row by working upwards from the given row, overwriting each row's data with the data of the row above it. This seems to work:

```
/**
 * Deletes row r from the array of landed Tetromino blocks.
 * @param r The row to delete from the landed array.
 **/
private void DeleteRow(int row) {
    for(int r = row; r > 0; r--) {
        for(int c = 0; c < Board.WIDTH; c++) {
            // Overwrite the value of this column from the row above.
            still[r, c] = still[(r - 1), c];
        }
    }
}
```

Where "still" is the 2D array defined as such.

```
private int[,] still;
```

And initialized here:

```
public Board() {
    still = new int[Board.HEIGHT, Board.WIDTH];
}
```

But in my CheckRows() method, which is what calls DeleteRow(), I seem to be having an issue where it will clear the first row that's passed to it, but subsequent rows are either ignored or it will delete the wrong row:

```
/**
 * Checks each row to see if they are full, and if so, deletes the row and adds to score.
 * @param score A long representing the current score, passed as reference.
 **/
public void CheckRows(ref long score) {
    List<int> rowsToClear = new List<int>();
    for(int r = 0; r < Board.HEIGHT; r++) {
        bool zero = false;
        for(int c = 0; c < Board.WIDTH; c++) {
            if(still[r, c] == 0) {
                zero = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!zero) rowsToClear.Add(r);
    }

    // Delete all the rows that did not contain zeros.
    if(rowsToClear.Count > 0) {
        // Add to the score depending on the number of rows cleared.
        score += (new int[4] { 40, 100, 300, 1200 })[rowsToClear.Count - 1];
        // Delete each row in the list and then increment all other row indices to account for
        // the fact that the rows above this one are being copied to this one.
        for(int i = (rowsToClear.Count - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            DeleteRow(rowsToClear[i]);
            rowsToClear.ForEach(x => x++);
        }
    }
}
```

I have to assume this has something to do with the line following the call to DeleteRow, where I increment the row numbers of the other rows that need to be cleared to account for the fact that I'm shifting each row downward to delete the row.

I have noticed though that if those rows are not deleted in the first CheckRows() call, they will be in the next iteration of the main game loop.

Is there some flaw in the logic I'm using? This is my first time making a Tetris game. I'm doing this to familiarize myself with C#, and I'm just not sure what the issue is here. Can someone else spot what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> I have to assume this has something to do with the line following the call to DeleteRow, where I increment the row numbers of the other rows that need to be cleared to account for the fact that I'm shifting each row downward to delete the row.

This is the line you are speaking of:

```
rowsToClear.ForEach(x => x++);
```

That line of code does absolutely nothing: The values will not be incremented.

You can perform an action on the element passed to the delegate in ForEach but you cannot replace it with a new value. Here is the documentation from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Modifying the underlying collection in the body of the Action delegate is not supported and causes undefined behavior.

That will not work and neither will this:

```
foreach (var thisNum in nums)
{
    thisNum++; // <== will not compile
}
```

This will increment the list:

```
for (int i = nums.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    nums[i]++;
}
```

[<== Try Me ==>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MCYD3Z)

Comment: I knew how to do it using a for loop, but I am trying to use lambda expressions and functional programming where I can to get used to the syntax. I was hoping that ForEach could be used as a map function and I could increment each member.

Answer (score 0):

After rearranging my CheckRows method around, I realized that the solution was that I needed to delete the rows in top to bottom order, as opposed to bottom to top.